# Random String Generation Based on Regular Expression-Python

Tags: python, regex, random, python-3.x

According to the [this](https://bitbucket.org/leapfrogdevelopment/rstr/) random strings can be generated importing rstr module.

```
import rstr
rstr.rstr('ABC')
```

but when I compile this following error is given?

```
ImportError: No module named rstr
```

I'm using python 3.3. What could be the reason?

Comment: This question is unrelated to random string generation, it's a problem with installing the package `rstr`

Answer (score 4):

You need to download the module and then make sure your python script can find it.

Comment: I have searched google many times and couldn’t find the link..:(. Could you please publish the link to download rstr module for python?

Comment: The link is on the page you linked to, in the box on the right-hand side, but here's a direct link: https://bitbucket.org/leapfrogdevelopment/rstr/get/c4a73a036e10.zip

Answer (score 1):

The rstr package should now be available on PyPI. You can install it by running `pip install rstr`

If you need more help, there's some [information about using pip here.](http://dubroy.com/blog/so-you-want-to-install-a-python-package/)